# Show std:string content in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In order to see `std::string` content in Eclipse I must each time to open `_M_dataplus`. Is it possible to configure Eclipse the way it always shows content of string when mouse is located over it without additional manipulation?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add apply a detail formatter in Eclipse via Java/Debug/Detail Formatters preference page. You will see your customized output only in Debug mode, therefore you must set a breakpoint, no "without manipulation", sorry.
Please take a look at this: [Debugging Tips - Human Readable Objects Section](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/04/again-10-tips-on-java-debugging-with-eclipse/)

Comment: std::string is C++, not Java